# What's the opposite of 儿化？非儿化？

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for the way to express the opposite of 儿化 in Chinese.

Let's assume 老头儿（lǎotóur）is the standard and it's rarely ever without an 儿. 老头 in this instance would be an exception. I want to express this by saying it's the opposite of 儿化.

规范 seems to express this in a few ways:

> 口语中多儿化
>
> 在口语中常读儿化音
>
> 口语中一般儿化

Which is okay.

I'd be happier with something like:

> 老头是老头儿的非儿化。

I'm not sure that any such terminology exists.

Comment: Then again, if a Beijinger reads 非儿化， what will you hear? 非儿化儿！：）Wouldn't the word you want be 普通话？ ‘老头’是普通话而‘老头儿’是北京话。

Comment: First off, as I noted, this is just an assumption. Secondly, 老头儿 is as much Mandarin as 老头 is; see Tuttle: "Note: 老头儿 lǎotóur is an impolite way of referring to an old man. As a form of address, 老头儿 lǎotóur is very rude. Instead, use the neutral term 老人 lǎorén or the polite terms 老先生 lǎoxiānsheng or 老大爷 lǎodàye." A Chinese-English Dictionary states that 儿化 pronunciation is "...typical of the pronunciation of putonghua, or standard Chinese and of some dialects." 两岸, which deals with the differences between TW and Mainland, also states "现代汉语中的一种语音现象." It's wrong to assume 儿化 is "northern."

Comment: Tuttle may have overstated his case. It is fairly easy to imagine a scenario where someone uses '老头’ or '老头儿‘ without causing grave insult, e.g. an old woman may refer to her '老公’ as '老头‘。 The point of '儿化’ is, such speakers will say 儿 if it is written or not. Thus 门 men becomes mer ‘这门（课）’. You will not pass a 普通话 exam if you constantly add 儿 to every other word. Do you really hear '儿化‘ a lot down South?

Comment: All the time: 村儿 猫儿 狗儿 猪儿 汁儿 水儿 摊儿 班儿 灯儿 馅儿 泡儿 坑儿 头儿 牌儿 虫儿 绳儿 锅儿

Comment: 你讲的是粤语 或者普通话了吗？

Comment: It's Mandarin bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of a term that exactly refers to the version without erization corresponding to the same word with erization.

「**非儿化**」 refers to the property of the sound:

> 「头儿」 is 「儿化的 / 儿化音」.
>
> 「头」 is 「**非儿化**的 / **非儿化**音」.

「**去儿化**」 refers to the process in which the erization is removed:

↑ 「去儿化」 is to 「儿化」 as "decentralize" is to "centralize"

> 「老头儿」**去儿化**之后得到「老头」。
>
> 「老头」是「老头儿」**去儿化**之后的结果。

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 儿化 isn't commonly used in 普通话(mandarin). It's basically a habit way of speaking among people in Beijing. For example, '您家里没人儿' is commonly used by Beijingers, while the standard way of mandarin is '您家里没有人'. So 儿化 is kind of a characteristic of the dialect in Beijing.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is only theoretically acceptable. But it will be strange to a Chinese. Let me think... I think that **儿化音** is a special form of spoken language. When you read a word like **老头儿**, **儿化音**  make it very **利索** (I don't know how to explain it in English, maybe **Smooth** or **Agile**)to read. However read it without **儿化音** （**非儿化音** in your words) is actually OK as well, no one will be surprised or something else because it is the normal form.

So don't keep in troubled in this question. If you really like labeling the way you speaking a word without **儿** as **非儿化**, I think **去儿化音** will be better which is mentioned in other answers and that may be helpful for your learning.